# Open the latest file

Tags: file, ms-access, vba

I have an Access form with the drawing number D-A1ER-1378-1601-0 listed which is also stored in a file folder.

I use the code below to open the pdf drawing, which works fine.

```vb
Public Sub OpenDWG()

    Dim strFile As String
    Dim PathPDF As String

    On Error GoTo Failure

    PathPDF = DLookup("[FilePath]", "[SettingsDrawingFilePathTbl]", "ID = 4")
    strFile = PathPDF & "\" & Screen.ActiveControl & ".pdf"
    If Len(Dir(strFile)) Then
        FollowHyperlink strFile
    Else
        MsgBox "No Document found for this Drawing Number, check Engineering Drawing Search File path in the Settings Tab and / drawing download files"
    End If
    Exit Sub

Failure:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

How do I adjust the strfile name

```
strFile = PathPDF & "\" & Screen.ActiveControl & ".pdf"
```

to get the form to open only the most recent file when a new version of the drawing is dropped into the folder. ie D-A1ER-1378-1601-0(2) will be the newest revision.

Comment: Sure you can rely on that naming schema (some changes filename)? If you use a form for upload, you can add a timestamp to the filenameur store the numbet and a timestamp in a tablem which you can query for max(TimeAdded). This is reliable and you can add older file later (some forgot) with the appropriate date. Else fetch all file with number in filename. Then sort by Len(filrname), filename.

Comment: Will be files missing from that folder? Like (2),(3),(5),(7) (in this case (7) is the last file)?

Comment: Exactly what is the active control? Why not select drawing from a combobox?

Comment: missing drawing error, just covers human error where the drawing is not stored in the folder or has been named incorrectly.

Comment: the Active control is the text box containing the drawing number. I only wanted the ability to access the very latest drawing so prevent quality issues.

Comment: @mupton You have to write a function that takes all the file names as strings and through some serious string manipulation figures out the biggest number. I tried to do it that way, but it got too big too fast for a single SO answer.

Comment: @mupton Also, there is the possibility to use the Dir function to get the files in order of the last created to newest. But that also creates a lot of other issues. Maybe you have to rethink your entire approach on this

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a comment, but I don't have enough points ot comment.

I think that you can use the Dir function to get all files beginning with the same characters, or with wild cards, etc. I'll have to look into how exactly to do this. You could populate an array with these, and use code to scan the array to determine the latest file. Or you could populate a temporary table amd then use the table contents as the course to a combo box to have the user select the desired file, sorted with the latest one on top.

If I get a chance, I'll conjure up some sample code an post it.

Comment: Please note that the files are not entered through Microsoft access , uploaded into a separate folder independently as there as huge amounts of data. Which is also why I use the hyperlink. Thanks all

Comment: if the document had the revision number on the end, will that make it easier to get the last version for example D-A1ER-1378-1601-0 (4)